# DIV is covered by previous DIV

Tags: html, css

I have below simple html

```
<body>
    <div style="position:fixed;width:100%;top:0;left:0;height:45px; background-color:silver">
        top
    </div>

    <div style="width:600px;background-color:yellow;margin:auto">
        bottom
    </div>
</body>
```

when I run the page in browser, the silver DIV covers the yellow one. I want to see the yellow one, right below the silver. How should I change it?

Comment: Give second/silver a top margin equal to the first/yellows height.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I thought about it but I like to know is there any way to not duplicate the hard coded value? as I see in answers, I need to add 45px in some othere places but like to know if I can avoid having 45 in 2 places.

Comment: No, you can't, for the reason I stated in my answer

Comment: Well, not if you use `position: fixed`, though there might be other ways achieve the same effect have a hard coded value written only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a `position: fixed` element is taken out of flow, other element will position themselves as if the `position: fixed` weren't there, so i your case your second need a margin equal to the height of the first

```html
<body>
    <div style="position:fixed;width:100%;top:0;left:0;height:45px; background-color:silver">
        top
    </div>

    <div style="width:600px;background-color:yellow;margin: 45px auto 0 auto">
        bottom
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I prefer this answer as it is not using style on body tag.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have it giving a fixed position. That takes the silver div outside the document flow.

Add a padding to your body, that will make your yellow div appear again.

```html
<body style="padding-top: 45px;">
    <div style="position:fixed;width:100%;top:0;left:0;height:45px; background-color:silver">
        top
    </div>

    <div style="width:600px;background-color:yellow;margin:auto">
        bottom
    </div>
</body>
```